# Java Spring Boot Random Port with Dockerfile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, port

If you're using Java Spring Boot, you can set the server port the application runs on to any port, but also to a random port:

```yaml
server:
  port: 0
```

However, when I now use a `Dockerfile` for my application, I won't know what port to `EXPOSE`. Is there any way to find this port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use a random port for the Spring app. Use the default port and have Docker expose that as whatever port you like.
2. Don't use a random port for the Spring app. Specify it via an environment variable and have Docker provide that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am not quite sure how that would work in a microservices architecture. For deployment I use portainer.io and Docker Swarm, how would I handle multiple instances of such a service without manually incrementing the port each time.

Comment: I believe you are thinking about this incorrectly. Containers are isolated and independent. You can have N number of Container instances of your Spring Boot app running, all using the same port INTERNALLY. I've not used portainer.io or Swarm. I've used Rancher, which has a software LoadBalancer that maps external, public, well-known IP:PORT to an internal Service (i.e. the N Containers running your app).

Answer (score 0):

when you started an app, you can see at console I think. As I know docker use 8080 or 8081.

EDIT 1:
Check this -> [link](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-59-difference-between-exposing-and-publishing-ports#:%7E:text=You%20can%20expose%20a%20port,%2Dp%2080%3A80%20flag.)

You can expose a port through your Dockerfile or use --expose and then publish it with the -P flag. This will bind the exposed port to your Docker host on a random port (verified by running docker container ls).

You can expose a port through your Dockerfile or use --expose and then publish it with the -p 80:80 flag. This will bind the exposed port to your Docker host on port 80, and it expects the exposed port is 80 too (adjust as necessary with HOST:CONTAINER).

You can ignore exposing anything and just use -p 80:80 in which case this doubles as both exposing AND publishing the port.